# Trial version of Home Server how to register

Tags: windows, license, home-server

I have installed a trial version of Home Server, and now have a full version how do I upgrade the trail version, I was hoping just to have to enter the License Key

Answer (score 1):

See this article : ["Windows Home Server: How to upgrade from trial or beta version?"](http://www.ditii.com/2008/02/06/windows-home-server-how-to-upgrade-from-trial-or-beta-version/).
It contains a list of the steps to take. Here is a small quote from the text:

> Upgrading Windows Home Server From a
>   Beta or 120 Day Evaluation Version
>
> The upgrade is actually a server
>   reinstallation as opposed to a new
>   install. This will keep all your
>   existing files and storage pool
>   intact. If this was a new install the
>   drives specified for the storage pool
>   would be formatted and one would lose
>   the data on the drive. Make sure you
>   make note of the users, passwords
>   settings and Windows Live ID you had
>   used in the previous install because
>   you will have to re-enter this
>   information. Also write down the fixed
>   IP address and DNS names you used in
>   the previous install.